# Create Athena table using JOOQ java

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, jooq

How can I create a Athena table using jooq library in java. Since Athena table uses syntax like create external table and we need to specifiy s3 bucket path also. I have a list of string from which i want to create the athena table. Can somebody suggest a way how i can do it with jooq library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Athena is using Presto behind the scenes, which currently isn't supported in jOOQ: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5414

You may get things to work on a best-effort basis, but  the integration simply isn't supported as of jOOQ 3.14.